# python: error while using strptime and timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, openerp-7

I'am trying to calculate a due date. Here's the code:

```
 from datetime import datetime,timedelta

 commande = self.pool.get('commandes').browse(cr, uid,commande_id,context=context)
 date_commande= datetime.strptime(commande.date_commande, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
 res['due_date']=date_commande+timedelta(days=20)
```

the field **due_date** is date type

I get this error:

```
XmlHttpRequestError INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.    Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

I tested the code without **timedelta** and i still got the same error

the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "werkzeug\serving.py", line 159, in run_wsgi    
  File "werkzeug\serving.py", line 146, in execute    
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140120-002508\Server\server\openerp\service\wsgi_server.py", line 417, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140120-002508\Server\server\openerp\service\wsgi_server.py", line 403, in application_unproxied
    result = handler(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140120-002508\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 528, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140120-002508\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 487, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 411, in __call__    
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140120-002508\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 487, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 411, in __call__    
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140120-002508\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 487, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "werkzeug\wsgi.py", line 411, in __call__    
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140120-002508\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 553, in dispatch
    result = handler(request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140120-002508\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 618, in <lambda>
    return lambda request: JsonRequest(request).dispatch(method)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20140120-002508\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 251, in dispatch
    body = simplejson.dumps(response)
  File "simplejson\__init__.py", line 286, in dumps    
  File "simplejson\encoder.py", line 228, in encode    
  File "simplejson\encoder.py", line 515, in _iterencode    
  File "simplejson\encoder.py", line 483, in _iterencode_dict    
  File "simplejson\encoder.py", line 483, in _iterencode_dict    
  File "simplejson\encoder.py", line 483, in _iterencode_dict    
  File "simplejson\encoder.py", line 525, in _iterencode    
  File "simplejson\encoder.py", line 202, in default    
TypeError: datetime.date(2014, 3, 3) is not JSON serializable
```

Please can someone tell me where i made a mistake?
Thanks

Comment: It's another error in your file which making it not working, not the timedelta as you wrote in the title

Comment: You need to check your http server log to find out what Internal Server Error it is referring to

Comment: still,everything is working fine when i get 'date_commande' value. but when i add 'strptime' it gave me this error.i already checked the format of the date and is: %Y-%m-%d

Sorry about the title i forgot to change it

Comment: @Anthony here's the error TypeError: datetime.date(2014, 3, 1) is not JSON serializable

Comment: @soukainas can you write the full traceback

Comment: @Mohamed sorry i am still learning python,i have no idea how to get it.

Comment: @soukainas the same place you got TypeError: datetime.date(2014, 3, 1) is not JSON serializable from it.
or from the log of the server if you are using apache2 you will find it in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in the response encoding to JSON as it can't parse datetime(date) to JSON, you should convert it to string using strftime function.

so you can try:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

 commande = self.pool.get('commandes').browse(cr, uid,commande_id,context=context)
 date_commande= datetime.strptime(commande.date_commande, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
 res['due_date']= datetime.strftime(date_commande+timedelta(days=20),"%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: You are welcome :), always try to read the traceback of the error to know the problem